# Getting 403 error when trying to call Google auth2.0 using C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth

Getting 403 error when trying to call Google auth2.0 through a serve side programing.

I tried everything but it's not working and there is no ducomentation available not even Google giving any support to resolve the issue.

Please help.

Comment: please provide some code segment to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: There is loads of official and unofficial documentation related to Google APIs and C#. I know this for a fact because i have personally written a lot of it over the last five years.  So your statement **there is no ducomentation available** is incorrect.   Please edit your question and show us what you are doing and describe any issues you are having.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. A quick search gives my [Google OAuth2 guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and that pages links to [guide for .NET OAuth 2.0 API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth). I would suggest giving them a go and post a [MCVE] of the problem. Remember: Do not post here your secret private.